# Simulate a set of number less than 20 that follows normal distribution

Tags: r, normal-distribution

What can I do to compel `R` to give me a sample less than 20, such that the sample will have mean = 0 and variance = `var`.

**MWE**

```
rnorm(20, mean=0, sd=1)
```

As the sample size gets larger, the sample gets closer to normal. How then can I make `R` to give me a sample of `n < 20` with a mean equal to zero and variance equal to whatever I specify?

Comment: not clear what you're asking: do you mean `rnorm(20, mean=0, sd=sqrt(var))` ... ????

Comment: yes, exactly what I mean

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
rnorm(20, mean=0, sd=sqrt(var))
```

For what it's worth

- your last paragraph sounds like a slightly confused statement of the [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem); there's no difficulty in creating small data sets that are normal, or Gaussian (the CLT says that *sums of N independent, identically distributed variables* approach normality as N goes to infinity ...)
- it would be worth using `v` rather than `var` to denote your variance, since `var()` is a built-in function in R (this is mostly harmless, but occasionally confusing).

Comment: y<-rnorm(20, mean=0, sd=sqrt(1));
 mean(y);
[1] 0.20924